# How to check the object value in enzyme jest test case

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My shallowobject contains span and span contains object

```
const exampleList = component.find('.module').children().find('span')
console.log(exampleList.at(1).find('span').debug())
```

output of console:

```
<span>
  {{ foo: 'foobar' }}
</span>
```

My expected value should be {{ foo: 'foobar' }}

I tried

```
expect(exampleList.at(1).find('span')).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ foo: 'foobar' }))
```

received :{}

Answer (score 0):

You have to try expecting the text content instead:

```
expect(exampleList.at(1).find('span').text()).toEqual({{ foo: 'foobar' }});
```

Comment: i am getting
 Expected: {"foo": "foobar"}
    Received: ""